# Why did the magician need Aladdin to retrieve the Lamp?

Tags: aladdin, 1001-nights

The magician already had a ring which housed a genie. While this genie wasn't as powerful as the lamp's genie, he was quite capable of transporting people to anywhere.

Why didn't the magician simply order the ring's genie to transport him near the lamp and then out of the cave?

Answer (score 8):

The magician did not want to enter the cave because it was **booby trapped**. So, better for him to send the "expendable" Aladdin in.

Sources:

1. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aladdin#Plot_summary)
2. [GradeSaver](https://www.gradesaver.com/the-arabian-nights-one-thousand-and-one-nights/study-guide/summary-aladdins-lamp)